# Populating database via jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In the below code, values are inserted manually: 13 and Aman. But what I am doing is reading a file and then till the completion of the file, I am inserting values from it into mysql database tables.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbctutorial", "root", "root");

    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    int val = st.executeUpdate("INSERT employee VALUES(" + 13 + "," + "'Aman'" + ")");
    System.out.println("1 row affected");

  }
}
```

I was trying to use each line like this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO home (home_no, arrival_time, duration, persons, price, origin_city) VALUES("+line+");";
```

How do I do it?

Comment: How many queries do you expect to execute from reading values from a file?

Comment: I am reading a file and then writing "line =br.readLine();" and while (line!= null) { .....the above line of code and then s.executeupdate(query)....IN my file, a lots of rows of data. So whatever My file is reading, i am keeping it in the line.

Comment: @Anthony: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how large the contents of the file that you are reading, it may be worth while to check [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) syntax, rather than executing queries in a `for` or `while` loop.

#### Edit:

Without seeing your code and `line` is the current line of the file you are reading and that you are using the syntax above to store the `query`, I would break down your problems,

- Check the `line` variable *prior* to executing the query
- Check how to insert the values manually opposed to reading the contents of the file, as you had shown above with `13` and `Aman`.
- Figure out how to piece those two together, may need string manipulation.

This should be all you need.

Comment: I dont know how we gonna use this command. MY data is in CSV file format.

Comment: If is comma separated, you can specify the delimiters when executing the statement. That is one perk of using that syntax. By any chance, is this anywhere homework related?

Comment: Ok, well now that changes things a bit. Considering this is homework based, I do not want to necessarily do all the work for you. I can, however, help you within the guidelines of your assignment. Can you post your entire code (including the `line = br.readLine()`) and tell me where you are lost? We can start from there.

Comment: sir,....plz try to help me...i wrote the whole code and it is compiled.But it is not executing.I cant post my code here but I can send you on your email account.my email id is: shib.shilpa@gmail.com..plz send urs .

Comment: Unfortunately that is not how this website works. Is there a reason why you cannot post the code? How about the snippet of your `while` loop when you are getting lost when executing the query? It's tough to help if you can't meet me halfway.

Comment: sir, someone could easily copy my code from here and submit it.

Comment: school is going to use some software to check if the code is copied from some place or not

Comment: @shilps, I was in the process of writing one, but first can you post what you have tried and how it didn't work?

Comment: I dont know , why is not executing. It is compiled properly.

Comment: I jst want to know the method of reading a file and then putting it in the mysql database tables. I know, how to read a file and then putting it into mysql database is what i dont know

Comment: @shilps, if you can do it manually then it shouldn't be a problem doing it when reading a file. It is practically the same but with more effort.

Comment: @Anthony - don't waste too much time on this guy.  He has a history ... to put it mildly.  Check out some of his past questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourFile.txt"));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
{
    // This time this loop runs, you will have the next time of your file.
    insertARecord(line.split(" "));
}
rd.close();

// A bit further

public void insertARecord(String[] data)
{
    // insert your record.
}
```